# Removing Trailing Substrings in SQL

Tags: sql, data-cleaning, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to cleanse (via SQL) some company names of common trailing suffixes like ' CO' and ' INC' without damaging the remaining string, eg 'PEETS COFFEE CO' would be correctly cleansed to 'PEETS COFFEE'.

I tried TRIM, but that only seems to work on single characters, and REPLACE, but that was too aggressive and returned 'PEETS FFEE' from my example above.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

*Edit/clarification:  I'm most interested in trailing occurances of "words" that will begin with spaces (eg " CORP" with a space, so CORP doesn't get removed from LABCORP).  But would also be interested in removing leading phrases as well, like the word "THE " from "THE HOME DEPOT" but still retaining those letters in "THEOLOPOLIS".*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Supply us with the concrete rules for the transformation. You have the list of the common suffixes? Do the suffixes have always a empty space before the company name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '( CO| INC)$', '', 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bd0802061710ee548e20652f336c17d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sql Server, you can go with:

```
Declare @text varchar(100)= 'PEETS COFFEE CO'
if @text like '% CO'
    select @text = left(@text, len(@text)- len(' CO'))
if @text like '% INC'
    select @text = left(@text, len(@text)- len(' INC'))
select @text
```

Output:

```
PEETS COFFEE
```

Comment: @MikeYokitis, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: Thanks for the coaching Eric, I did.  I'm a noob  at SO so the coaching was instructive.